# Как из 32 одинаковых методов сделать 1?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня в программе есть 32 кнопки (каждая соответствует одному человеческому зубу). Внутри кода кнопок лишь один метод, который в качестве аргумента принимает номер кнопки. Получается так:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButtonState(0);
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButtonState(1);
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButtonState(2);
    }
```

...

И таких методов 32. Можно как то это записать более компактно?
Например что то вроде:

```
    private void Button_Click_[numberOfButton](object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButtonState(numberOfButton);
    }
```

**Правка 1:**

Нашел пример, но не пойму, как он работает. Если я повешу это на все кнопки, то где указывается аргумент для метода ToggleButtonState? Я же прям внутри обработчика не могу указать, а то он одинаковый для всех кнопок будет

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//это повесь на всех баттонКЛиках
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    switch(b.Tag)
    case 1:
        Method(?);break;
}
```

Comment: А в шарпе нельзя разве создать один обработчик, а потом на каждую кнопку его отдельно повесить?

Comment: Да, действительно можно. Нашел пример, но не могу с ним разобраться

Comment: В вашей случае, `sender` - это та кнопка, которая была нажата, с ней вы можете делать что угодно через эту ссылку. Я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать с ToggleButtonState, но уверен, что этого можно добиться с помощью `sender`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обратите внимание на вот это выражение:

```
b.Tag
```

Свойство `Tag` у кнопки вы можете назначить произвольно. К примеру, можно туда записать то число, которое в дальнейшем должно быть передано методу `ToggleButtonState`.

Answer (score 4):

После InitializeComponent() добавляете:

```
  this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAll_Click);
  this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAll_Click);
```

и обработчик

```
    private void buttonAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var name=((Button)sender).Name;
        var num = name.Replace("Button",String.Empty);//от Button12 остается "12"
        var intNum =Int32.Parse(num);//конвертируем string->Int
        ToggleButtonState(intNum);           

    }
```